# Avoiding name conflicts in ~/.config/nvim/lua/

Tags: neovim, lua

I've installed [telescope.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) plugin for NeoVim. Now, I would like to put some configuration code related to this plugin in this file:

```
~/.config/nvim/lua/telescope.lua
```

In my `init.lua` file, I've loaded the plugin, and I've added this line, intending it to load my custom `telescope.lua`:

```
require('telescope')
```

However, this fails silently. I know think the problem is a name conflict with the telescope plugin. If I rename my file to something else, like `~/.config/nvim/lua/tt.lua`, and change the line correspondingly, it works as expected:

```
require('tt')
```

Is there a way to load the file I intend, without running into naming conflicts? Can I do something like this in my `init.lua` file?

```
require('~/.config/nvim/lua/telescope.lua')
```

Answer (score 3):

Most configs I've seen handle this by putting a `my` directory inside the `lua` directory. This would allow you to do:

```lua
require("my.telescope")
```